# Processing Multiple Images

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am writing an image processing program, which works well, but I need to process multiple images.

First, I made an array of images:

```
images = ((image1.tif),
          (image2.tif),
          (image3.tif))
```

Then, I created a for loop:

```
for image in images:
    dna = cv2.imread(image)
    {code}
```

The problem is, whenever I run the code, the console returns an error of

```
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, tuple found
```

At this line:

```
dna = cv2.imread(image)
```

It seems that the program is trying to process the whole array at once. I thought that the loop worked by processing one image in the array at a time? Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap the filenames using single or double quotes:

```
images = (('image1.tif'),
          ('image2.tif'),
          ('image3.tif'))
```

You can also use list instead of tuples:

```
images = ['image1.tif', 'image2.tif', image3.tif']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
images = (("image1.tif"),
          ("image2.tif"),
          ("image3.tif"))
```